# Boolean int conversion issue

Tags: c#, integer, boolean

I am working on a trading API (activex from interactive brokers)which has a method called:

```
void reqMktDataEx(int tickerId, IContract contract, string generalDetails, int snapshot)
```

The issue is around the last parameter "int snapshot" which obviously requires an int input which actually indicates that whether trader wanna snapshot market data or not. So I guess that if I set it to non-zero, then the implicit conversion would convert this non-zero to be `bool` value "true".

However, I am using c# to connect to this api. Everything was fine until this one. I tried this:

A. `void reqMktDataEx(1, AUDUSD, "100", 0)`
Please ignore the first three parameters "1, AUDUSD, "100"", the only matter is the last one 0 as int. I got paused during debugging and the information is :
"Specified cast is not valid. Invalidcastexception is unhandled" and "when casting from a number, the number must not be infinity".

After this I learned that here is a difficulty for c# to treat 1 as bool true and 0 as bool false IMPLICITLY according this
web http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-bool-int

B. I tried this
`void reqMktDataEx(1, AUDUSD, "100", Convert.ToInt16(false))` I got similar error again.

C. I tried again this one:

```
void reqMktDataEx(1, AUDUSD, "100", int.Parse("false"))
```

the complaint is input string was not in a correct format. Make sure that you method arguments are in the right format.

MY GUESS:
Here is a inside configuration of C# which does not treat 0 as false and 1 as true. Is there any way to solve?

**First Edit**

As suspected by one professional programmer below, I post the contract class and audusd definition here for him.

```
namespace InteractiveBrokersTradingSystem
{
    class Contract:TWSLib.IContract
    {
        public int conId { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public string secType { get; set; }
        public string expiry { get; set; }
        public double strike { get; set; }
        public string right { get; set; }
        public string multiplier { get; set; }
        public string exchange { get; set; }
        public string primaryExchange { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string localSymbol { get; set; }
        public int includeExpired { get; set; }
        public object comboLegs { get; set; }
        public object underComp { get; set; }
        public string comboLegsDescrip { get; set; }
        public string secIdType { get; set; }
        public string secId { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace InteractiveBrokersTradingSystem
{
    class Forex:Contract
    {
        public Forex(string preCurrency,string baseCurrency)
        {
            //conId = 14433401;
            symbol = preCurrency;
            secType = "CASH";
            exchange = "IDEALPRO";
            currency = baseCurrency;
            strike = 0;
            includeExpired = 0;
            primaryExchange = "IDEALPRO";       
        }
    }
}
```

The method I use to call the reqMktDataEx:
implementation first, simple inheritance:

```
public void MyReqMarketData(int tickId, IContract contract, string tickTypes, int snapshot)
{
    reqMktDataEx(tickId, contract, tickTypes, snapshot);
}


 private void AudButtonItemItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
 {
     Forex audusd = new Forex("AUD", "USD");

      _myTwsClass.MyReqMarketData(1,audusd, "100", 0);
  }
```

**Second Edit**:

```
  System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'InteractiveBrokersTradingSystem.Forex' to type 'TWSLib.IContract'.
  Source=InteractiveBrokersTradingSystem
```

It seems that here is some casting problem between the forex class I defined and the Icontract com thing. Here is my new definition:

```
namespace InteractiveBrokersTradingSystem
{
    class Forex
    {
        public int conId { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public string secType { get; set; }
        public string expiry { get; set; }
        public double strike { get; set; }
        public string right { get; set; }
        public string multiplier { get; set; }
        public string exchange { get; set; }
        public string primaryExchange { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string localSymbol { get; set; }
        public int includeExpired { get; set; }
        public object comboLegs { get; set; }
        public object underComp { get; set; }
        public string comboLegsDescrip { get;set; }
        public string secIdType { get; set; }
        public string secId { get; set; }

        public Forex(string preCurrency,string baseCurrency)
        {
            //conId = 0;
            //symbol = preCurrency;
            //secType = "CASH";
            //expiry = null;
            //strike = double.Parse("0");
            //right = null;
            //multiplier = null;
            //exchange = "IDEALPRO";
            //primaryExchange = "IDEALPRO";
            //currency = baseCurrency;
            //localSymbol = null;
            //includeExpired = 0;
            //comboLegs = null;
            //underComp = null;
            //comboLegsDescrip = null;
            //secType = null;
            //secId = null;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see that the Forex class inherits from the TWS.IContract. how it could not be cast to Icontract successively?

Comment: why aren't you just calling it `reqMktDataEx(1, AUDUSD, "100", false)` ?

Comment: I suspect this has nothing to do with the boolean.

Comment: @Yahia: because there's no implicit conversion?

Comment: The API: http://interactivebrokers.com/php/apiUsersGuide/apiguide/activex/reqmktdataex.htm

Comment: then the question is why aren't you just calling it `reqMktDataEx(1, AUDUSD, "100", 0)` or `reqMktDataEx(1, AUDUSD, "100", 1)` ?

Comment: Dear all, I went to shopping. Let me clarify little bit further. TO YAHIA: reqMktDataEx(1, AUDUSD, "100", 1), i tried this, the complaint during the debugger is "when casting from a number , the number should not be an infinity". I guess that although this method requires int as last argument, api would try to cast it to bool before sending it to the trading software. However, c#, not like VB, does not naturally cast 0 to true. Then here is some "translation" confilict.

Comment: There is no issue of implicit or explicit conversion of anything to anything. According to the specification given in by Merlyn Morgan-Graham's link, the call `reqMktDataEx(1, AUDUSD, "100", 0)` should have worked. Since it does not work, there is something else going on. The exception is probably being thrown by the implementation of the trading API, not by your code.

Comment: To MikeNakis, you probably right. It MAY about api. This api provides an VB example to communicate with this api. In that example, the definition of this method from API is same as require an int snapshot as last argument. However, in that Example, the VB language simply just use a boolean property called snapshotMktdata as last input. The method has been used in VB in this way: public readonly property snapshotMktData() as boolean; call tws1.reqMktDataEx(myOrder.orderId, myOrder.Contract, generaicTagesstring, snapshotMktData ), you see? It use boolean as last argument directly and no issue.

Comment: I think the bug is in the API wrapper you're using.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion of a `bool` to an `int`.  Only an explicit one:

```
Convert.ToInt32(someBool)
// or...
someBool ? 1 : 0
```

[From that site you linked](http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-bool-int):

> First, you cannot implicitly convert from bool to int. The C# compiler uses this rule to enforce program correctness. It is the same rule that mandates you cannot test an integer in an if statement.

### Edit

`int` doesn't have a concept of infinity.  Only `float` and `double` do.  This means it won't be related to that parameter, unless that parameter just controls the flow of the code that is actually crashing.  Which still means it isn't the conversion causing the problem.

You're getting a different error for `int.Parse("false")` because it is expecting a number, not a true/false value.  This will always throw an exception at runtime, but it will throw in *your* code, not in the library's code.

I'm starting to think it is the second parameter, `contract`, for which you've supplied `AUDUSD`.

Comment: I do not think this one solved the question. I understand your way to convert. However, the problem is not whether I can convert it in my code, it is about if I follow the method declaration to input an int as last argument. It complaints: "Specified cast is not valid. Invalidcastexception is unhandled" and "when casting from a number, the number must not be infinity". It seems like the api read my last argument and try to cast it to boolean and failed it within the c# language enviorenment.

Comment: @Wenhao.SHE: That API isn't public.  It is really hard to tell what it is doing.  How are you accessing it via C#?  If the signature is `int`, I think the C# wrapper is the culprit, and you're doing nothing wrong in your code.  Also, how can you be sure that the **last** parameter is causing the error?  You haven't told us the stack trace or line number of the error, so that we can say whether it is your source, or the wrapper code's source.

Comment: The api is open for read here: http://www.interactivebrokers.com/php/apiUsersGuide/apiguide.htm    please go to the ActiveX directory->Market Data subdirectory-> reqMktDataEx.     The definition in interface from API is: public virtual void reqMktDataEx(int tickerId, TWSLib.IContract contract, string genericTicks, int snapshot).    The reason I know it has problem is the the exception type changes when I try these as last argument: a. int input "1" b. Convert.ToInt16(false) c. int.Parse("false").

Comment: In VB example, they use in this way: call tws1.reqMktDataEx(1, audusd, "100", true) with success. However, c# does not allow me to input a bool value true as last argument, so I tried out int 0 and 1 with complaint that when cast from number, it should not be infinity.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt16(false)` converts to a `short`, which gets implicitly converted to an `int`.  `int.Parse("false")` will flat out bomb out in *your* code, because `false` isn't an int - that code is just wrong, and will fail at runtime.  That is why you get different errors.  This does not prove that it is the 4th parameter causing the problem.

Comment: I'm almost completely sure now that `audusd` is the problem, not the 4th parameter.  This makes a lot more sense, as an `int` doesn't have a concept of infinity.  Only `float` and `double` types do.

Comment: There is probably no implicit conversion from string to `TWSLib.IContract` (or a wrong one)

Comment: Dear Merlyn and Emo, may you see my updated edited post again. I posted the suspecious contract and audusd implementation above. Here is indeed a double properties in that class. The 0 value for the double property strike is reasonable since it is about forex and no strike here. May you answer me? Thanks!!!

Comment: When looking at http://interactivebrokers.com/php/apiUsersGuide/apiguide.htm#apiguide/activex/reqmktdataex.htm I can't help but notice that some of the properties have `()` and the last one (secId) hasn't. The fact that VB is working fine and C# not might have to do with late binding or implicit conversions that are possible in VB but not in C#. Either way it is very hard for me to test this with out having the actual bits.

Comment: Dear Emo, I also noticed that. It seems very hard to do. What is the difference when properties have () or not?

Comment: Dear Merlyn, you are right that it is about the Icontract stuff and totally not about the last argument since I tried another method the api provided public virtual void reqContractDetails(int reqId, Icontract contract) and  I used in this way reqcontractdetails(1, audusd). And i got exception says that cast from a number infinity as well. I checked this infinity number cast exception: InvalidCastException is thrown if either

Comment: a) during a conversion from a Single or a Double to a Decimal, the source value is infinity, Not-a-Number (NaN), or too large to be represented as the destination type, or b) a failure occurs during an explicit reference conversion.  I guess I am in case b since here is only on double property and even I did not assign any number to it, this exception still throw. I guess it means something Emo metioned about that some property has () and some not. It is pain to use COM.

Comment: @Wenhao.SHE: I tried to look at the stuff relating to the `double` in that interface, but I don't know stocks well enough to understand what formulas they'd use under the covers, so I can't tell you why that exact error is occuring.  The problem is definitely specific to this library now that you've got the bool thing figured out.  If you keep having problems with *that* part, you could open a separate question.  The code from this question seems appropriate to add to the new question.  Also, adding the signature of the `IContract` interface to your new question might help too.

Comment: @Wenhao.SHE: Oh, I see the other answer you posted now.  Cool.  Glad we got you this far :)

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham May you check my another post as following question>? I even want to send my project to you which only includes five files including three simplest inheritance csharp class? link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477107/invalidcastexception-when-using-activex-in-c-sharp-project  thanks lot man!

Answer (score 11):

One more way is to have extension method:

```
public static class BooleanExtensions
{
    public static int ToInt(this bool value)
    {
        return value ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

then it can be used:

```
bool result = false;
result.ToInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

make field tinyint in database
tinyint fieldname;
c# code

```
convert.toint32(fieldname.tostring());//returns 1 or 0
to get boolean value

covert.tobool(fieldname.tostring()) ;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There's no implicit cast to int from bool. So make your own. Then add them up.

```
        Boolean
            byFinancialCenter = false,
            byProvider = false,
            byServiceSite = false,
            byProcedure = false;
        int b2i(bool source) => source ? 1 : 0;
        int ForeignKeyCount() => b2i(byFinancialCenter) + b2i(byProvider) + b2i(byServiceSite) + b2i(byProcedure);
```

The b2i is generic, as I needed the specific count in several places, including the last function makes it easy to use. Also, for maintenance, having the embedded function just under the bools makes it more likely that subsequent developers will see what's happening.