# c# Linq expression to return chosen value of checkbox

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have `checkbox` within my windows form and I want to pass values below to database as shown in example below too, but the `if... else...` statement will make the rest of my code **unreachable** and my script will not be execute it, so how I can avoid that case ?

I am think of about dose using Linq expression to return chosen value of `checkbox` directly to database parameter can avoid that case ? if yes how please ?

```
int active;

if (chkboxActive.Checked)
{ active = 1; } 
else
{ active = 0; }

cmd.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = active;
```

Comment: Linq? No, that makes no sense. Ternary operator? Sure! `int active = chkboxActive.Checked ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: @DavidG please would like to provide me an example ?

Comment: I'd just use `.Value = Convert.ToInt32(chkboxActive.Checked);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# boolean int conversion issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457366/c-sharp-boolean-int-conversion-issue)

Comment: Why does the `if` statement make anything unreachable?

Comment: not anything the rest of the code

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't make sense to use Linq here at all. However, you could use the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```
int active = chkboxActive.Checked ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: This is nice. It could also have been `int active = 0; if(chxboxActive.Checked) active = 1;` on two-three lines

Answer (score 0):

Why Linq, You can directly convert the Checked value to Integer, By using,
Convert.ToInt32(some boolean)
Editing code to match your format,

```
int active;
active=Convert.ToInt32(chkboxActive.Checked);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = active;
```

This is your complete code, remove the if else part.

Comment: no my friend that is will pass only  the checked value and will not pass the unchecked one

Comment: Hi Sam, For unchecked one's it will pass 0. It should be zero and it should pass.

Comment: What do you mean by `unchecked one`? The .Checked property is either true (1) or false (0).

Comment: I when true return `1` when false return `0` after that i would pass the value to database paramter

Comment: I mean to say if it is Checked == false it will be converted to zero, check my updated answer.

Comment: Please try executing the code first, before jumping to conclusion. 
chkboxActive.Checked is a bool, which means either true or false,
Convert.ToInt32 will give you 1 if it is true and 0 if it is false.

Comment: Personally I would not recommend using this method. While it does work, it's kindy nasty to do a conversion like this.

Comment: public static int ToInt32(bool value) {
            return value? Boolean.True: Boolean.False;
        }
 This is the implementation of Convert.ToInt32, which will be same as using a ternary operator. My belief is that using a Conversion method will add to readability by making the intent clear, and also works fine for three state checkbox

Comment: So you think wrapping a method around a single line of code makes it more readable? I disagree with that. The only reason that method exists is for consistency across the framework.