# How can I change a bool to a 0 or a 1, can I cast it?

Tags: c#

I have this method:

```
public void UpdatePhrase(PHRASE phraseColumn, bool value, string phraseId) 
{
   sql = string.Format("UPDATE Phrase SET " + phraseColumn.Text() + " = {0} WHERE PhraseId = '{1}'", value, phraseId);
        App.DB.RunExecute(sql);
}
```

It's not working correctly as it seems like I need the value of {0} needs to be a 0 or a 1.

Is there a simple way that I can take value and change it to be a 0 or a 1?

Comment: or use phraseid?1:0

Comment: Simple ternary `value ? 1 : 0`

Comment: Just put (value?1:0)

Comment: Slightly OT but, ___do not___ create SQL queries like this, they are prone to SQL injection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# boolean int conversion issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457366/c-sharp-boolean-int-conversion-issue)

Comment: There is not better way than use parameters. Sorry but your  _App.DB.RunExecute(sql);_ seems not to be able to receive parameters. You need a certain level of refactoring here

Comment: @phuzi advising people to use parameters is **never** OT... (as long as the question does actually relate to SQL, I suppose...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just do `value ? 1 : 0`, it's that easy!

Answer (score 9):

@Sean has given to you the natural fix to your problem, but, in my view, what you really need to do here is to refactor your *App.Db.RunExecute* to receive parameters, so you can write

```
public void UpdatePhrase(PHRASE phraseColumn, bool value, string phraseId) 
{
   sql = "UPDATE Phrase SET " + phraseColumn.Text() + " = @v WHERE PhraseId = @id";
   List<SqlParameter> prms = new List<SqlParameter>
   {
      new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@v", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Boolean, Value = value},
      new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@id", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = phraseId}
   };
   App.DB.RunExecute(sql, prms);
}
```

This will *partially* remove the Sql Injection problem (I say partially because that *phraseColumn.Text()* is still source of concerns if its value comes from the user input)

Now *RunExecute* should change to

```
void RunExecute(string sqlCommand, List<SqlParameter> prms = null)
{
     // usual code to open connection and create a command
     ......

     // If the caller passes a parameters list, add them to the command
     if(prms != null)
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(prms.ToArray());

     // Now execute the command
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The change to *RunExecute* uses an optional argument, so your current code is not affected by the presence of the new argument but you will be able to write better Sql code from now on.

Comment: I would like to know the reason for the downvote. If there is something wrong in this answer I think that we all need to know and avoid it.

Comment: Great answer. Not only does this help answer OP's question, adding the `SqlParameters` to a list and then using `cmd.Parameters.AddRange(list.ToArray())` is a new concept (to me) that seems extremely useful and clean: +1

Comment: I'd image that the reason for the downvote is that you don't actually answer the question, which is now to convert a boolean to either 1 or 0. Whilst your answer provides a great example of using parameterized queries it doesn't once address the original question.

Comment: You have a point here @Sean. I haven't answered that because we have something like 3 answers already here that explain how to transform a boolean to an integer. (and two are just a bad copy of yours). It makes no sense to me to repeat again the first natural fix. So I think that to make my answer better I just need to acknowledge your work.

Answer (score 1):

you can do (GetHashCode on booleans returns a constant 1/0, no calculation):

```
true.GetHashCode() // 1
false.GetHashCode() // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value ? 1 : 0
```

as in @Sean answer or

```
Convert.ToInt32(value)
```

> [ToInt32(Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Boolean_) Converts the specified Boolean value to the
>   equivalent 32-bit signed integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `int count = updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery;` so `if count>0,` it means our mission is done 1 (True) , otherwise 0 (False)

```
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Var" , "Johne");

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        int count = updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery;
        if (count > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

I hope you got the point ^_^.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public object VerySimplyCompactFastTrueBestConvertObjectToInt(object whatNeedToConvertBro, object whatTypeIsYoNeedBro)
    {
        var typeOfConvertingObject = whatNeedToConvertBro.GetType();
        var objWhatWillBeaReturnedInOut = new object();
        if ((typeOfConvertingObject == whatTypeIsYoNeedBro.GetType()) == true)
        {
            objWhatWillBeaReturnedInOut = Convert.GetTypeCode(whatTypeIsYoNeedBro);
        }
        return objWhatWillBeaReturnedInOut;
    }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
public void UpdatePhrase(PHRASE phraseColumn, bool value, string phraseId) 
{
   sql = string.Format("UPDATE Phrase SET {phraseColumn} = {value ? 1 : 0} WHERE PhraseId = '{phraseId}'");
        App.DB.RunExecute(sql);
}
```

But that can be subject to SQL injection attacks, so better to write it as a parameterised query.

Comment: `(int)value` will not even compile

Comment: True, I was thinking in C for a moment. Fixed.

Answer (score -2):

For scenarios needing ***extreme performance***, you can use the [System.­Runtime.­CompilerServices.­Unsafe](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/) package to perform this conversion directly inline. This will result in native code that contains no branching or function calls.

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

/// ...

bool _bool;
byte _byte;

_bool = true;
_byte = Unsafe.As<bool, byte>(ref _bool);
Console.WriteLine(_byte);           //  -->  1

_bool = false;
_byte = Unsafe.As<bool, byte>(ref _bool);
Console.WriteLine(_byte);           //  -->  0
```

You can also use this method to set up a `ref local byte` variable which existentially represents the ***instantaneous identity*** of the `Boolean`, but viewed as a `byte`. This might be useful for persistently monitoring a changing `{ false, true }` using a `{ 0, 1 }` interpretation.

```
class Program
{
    static bool _bool;

    static void Main()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { while (true) _bool = !_bool; });

        // define a "ref local" that persistently views Boolean value '_bool' as a byte
        ref byte _byte = ref Unsafe.As<bool, byte>(ref _bool);

        while (true)
            Console.Write(_byte + " ");
    }
};
```

If you're unfamiliar with `ref`, with this technique just shown there is no "machinery" involved in any sort of "updating" or "conversion" whenever the value changes, because the `ref byte` is actually just a different "view" of the original `Boolean` entity itself.

The output is somewhat mesmerizing.

[image]