# How to create 1 / 0 returning type for bool?

Tags: c#, casting, typecasting-operator

In C#, how it's possible to create custom type/cast for i.e. `bool` ? To better explain, i want that such expression:

```
bool cond=...;
int myVar=  cond as customType;
```

so, i want `customType` to behave as `myVar` become either `0` or `1`, depending of `cond` (if true, then 1, else 0).

Is that possible?

---

*please, don't offer me `cond ? 1 : 0` solution or others. I asked exactly what I asked, so re-read (or analyze) it if before flagging.*

Comment: Why introduce a `customType`? Why not just `myVar = cond ? 1 : 0`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boolean int conversion issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457366/boolean-int-conversion-issue)

Comment: Convert.ToBoolean(expression) ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EjCWMQ)? (custom type with implicit operators)

Comment: You can define a conversion but it `as` doesn't invoke user defined conversions

Comment: @SirRufo you could have posted it as answer, thanks ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do so. If you want a custom type that behaves like a built-in type, you must take care to override some methods inherited from `System.Object`. Also, you need conversion operators.

Let's create a struct called `Logical` having an `int` property `Value`.

```
public readonly struct Logical : IEquatable<Logical>
{
    public Logical(int value)
    {
        Value = value == 0 ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public Logical(bool cond)
    {
        Value = cond ? 1 : 0;
    }

    public int Value { get; }

    ... conversions and overrides
}
```

It has 2 constructors, allowing you to build a value from either an `int` or `bool`.

We can declare implicit conversions to convert between `bool` and `Logical`, `int` and `Logical` and `Logical` and `bool`.

```
public static implicit operator Logical(bool cond) => new Logical(cond);

public static implicit operator Logical(int i) => new Logical(i);

public static implicit operator bool(Logical logical) => logical.Value != 0;
```

It is also good to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to easily be able to compare values or to add them to dictionaries or hash sets.

```
public bool Equals(Logical other) // Implements IEquatable<Logical>
{
    return Value.Equals(other.Value);
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is Logical logical) {
        return Equals(logical);
    }
    return base.Equals(obj);
}

public override int GetHashCode() => Value.GetHashCode();
```

If you override `Equals`, it is natural to overload `==` and `!=`

```
public static bool operator ==(Logical a, Logical b) => a.Value == b.Value;
public static bool operator !=(Logical a, Logical b) => a.Value != b.Value;
```

Finally, we override `ToString` to be able to print Logicals.

```
public override string ToString() => Value == 0 ? "FALSE" : "TRUE";
```

Now, we can do these sort of things:

```
double x = 3.14;
Logical logical = x > 0.0;
bool b = logical;

Console.WriteLine($"logical = {logical}");
Console.WriteLine($"b       = {b}");

logical = -3;
Console.WriteLine($"logical = {logical}");
Console.WriteLine($"logical.Value = {logical.Value}");
logical = 0;
Console.WriteLine($"logical = {logical}");
Console.ReadKey();
```

It prints:

```
logical = TRUE
b       = True
logical = TRUE
logical.Value = 1
logical = FALSE
```

There is more you can do. `System.Bool`, for instance, implements `IComparable`, `IComparable<bool>`, `IConvertible` and `IEquatable<bool>`. It also has static `Parse` and `TryParse` methods. You could also overload other operators. See: [Overloadable operators (Operator overloading, C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading#overloadable-operators).

Comment: thanks, just to ask shortly, can I use that directly `cond as Logical` , and it will return either `1` or `0`.

Comment: See `Logical logical = x > 0.0;`. The Boolean cond `x > 0.0` is automatically converted to `Logical`. You can then access the value with `logical.Value` or you could add the conversion `public static implicit operator int(Logical logical) => logical.Value;` and write `var i = (int)(Logical)cond;` where `cond` is a `bool`. You can also change `ToString`, so that it returns `"0"` or `"1"`. And Instead of creating a type, you could also create an extension method in a static class `public static int ToLogicalInt(this bool cond) => cond ? 1 : 0;` and write `cond.ToLogicalInt()`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457366/boolean-int-conversion-issue) is probably the answer that you should be using unless you have a very good reason not to.

However, just because it's interesting, you could alternatively use some version of the following struct so that conversion is implicit and you have the bool value and the int value both available simultaneously without any extra memory usage:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct BoolToInt
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public readonly bool booleanValue;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public readonly int integerValue;

    public BoolToInt(bool booleanValue)
    {
        this.integerValue = 0; //irrelevant, will be overwritten, but the compiler can't figure this out
        this.booleanValue = booleanValue;
    }
}
```

You could make the boolean value mutable if you want to be able to change it, however this does go against the general principles of struct usage.
I would strongly advise not making the integerValue field mutable.

Comment: thanks for answer, so, i can use `cond as BoolToInt` expression,rigjt?

Comment: No. If you want to do that you'd have to use the chosen answer. With this one, you just use the integerValue property, no need for a cast (as).

Answer (score -1):

If you need the value of a bool (1 or 0) you should use the GetHashCode function 
[Boolea.GetHashCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.8)

I've put an example here

```
bool v1 = true;
bool v2 = false;
int res;

Console.WriteLine($"v1: {v1.GetHashCode()}, v2: {v2.GetHashCode()}");
```

Comment: As it mentioned in my link ,The Boolean class implements true as the integer, one, and false as the integer, zero. However, a particular programming language might represent true and false with other values.

Comment: Also, the implementation of `GetHashCode` might change at any time.